# Passing href value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several links in the HTML which reload the page on click, but I'd like to get the values of each individual href when the user clicks the link and store it into the variable xhash:

HTML:

```
<a href='#taba' id='passid'>Link 1</a>
<a href='#tabb' id='passid'>Link 2</a>
<a href='#tabc' id='passid'>Link 3</a>
<a href='#tabd' id='passid'>Link 4</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
var xhash = document.getElementById("passid").hash;
});
```

When the page reloads, it only displays #taba as its the first element in the HTML. Is it possible to pass the href/hash that the user clicks into xhash variable? I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: does it call the javascript? try to put an alert('javascritcalled'); command before the var xhash

Comment: You are using the `.on()` wrong. First input should be the event (like click, submit, etc)

Comment: You're re-using `id` tags, which is not how `id` works; an `id` is meant to be unique on the page. So you're always going to get the same element. `this` would refer to the element firing the event.

Comment: yeah, it calls the javascript - it just resets back to #taba though, I'm trying to pass the href/hash into the URL string using window.location.href - this works but it goes to #taba everytime

Comment: you cant use same id for different anchor tag. ID must be unique.

Comment: _“Is it possible to pass the href/hash that the user clicks into xhash variable?”_ – to what _actual_ purpose? You should first of all describe the real/main problem you are trying to solve here. (See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score -2, accepted):

HTML Code

```
<a href='#taba' class='passid'>Link 1</a>
<a href='#tabb' class='passid'>Link 2</a>
<a href='#tabc' class='passid'>Link 3</a>
<a href='#tabd' class='passid'>Link 4</a>
```

JQuery Code

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var xhash = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: This is full of bad practices

Comment: Interesting how the least-best answer on these low-skill questions so often gets accepted as the best.

Comment: This probaly was the first post for the TS, if you can't read any further, you're no worthy of possible better answers

Answer (score 2):

First, you cant give multiple items the same ID, thats what class is for, an ID may only occur once per page. Then, you can use `this` to access the clicked element:

```
<a href='#taba' class='passid'>Link 1</a>
<a href='#tabb' class='passid'>Link 2</a>
<a href='#tabc' class='passid'>Link 3</a>
<a href='#tabd' class='passid'>Link 4</a>

$('.passid').on('click', function(){
    alert( this.href ); // No need for jQuery, JS is a lot faster with this
});
```

You are using the `on()` improperly, the first input should be the event.
Offtopic: You use single quotes arround your values. That is not wrong, but in general people use double quotes in html.

If you are looking to trigger some code when the hash changes:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    alert('yay, hashchange' );
});
```

Comment: Single and double quotes are both perfectly compatible; the "single quotes are evil" dictum came from the (ridiculous) XHTML wannabe days, when XML requires double-quotes. Technically, quotes aren't even necessary in many cases. Let's not pass "everyone else is doing it" as "right way to do it". `:)`